# Hyperledger composer javascript return value

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to create smart contract for login. When users input username and password are correct its will **return true** and incorrect **return false** to my web application.

Model

```
participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String username
  o String password
}

transaction SampleLogin {
  --> SampleParticipant participant
  o String inputUsername
  o String inputPassword
}
```

Transaction

```
function sampleLogin(tx) {

  var username = tx.participant.username;
  var password = tx.participant.password;
  var inputUsername = tx.inputUsername;
  var inputPassword = tx.inputPassword;

  if (username == inputUsername && password == inputPassword){
    //return true;
  }else{
    //return false;
  }  
}
```

I want get with this. https://localhost:3000/api/SampleLogin

```
return True or False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TP returns a 200 from the REST API (transaction submitted). The TP returns a Promise which can be resolved as a Boolean, having value either true or false - depending on your result (above). You wouldn't `return` out from the TP. Seems to me your login code would be better in a client app - otherwise you're creating a transaction for each and every login set, good or bad and with the id and password stored in the ledger. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes sir, I want this. ^^