# Is it possible to create a read-only transaction in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new to hyperledger composer and I am trying to create a read only transaction in which I have to get information for 2 different assets and then do some post processing on it and return the combined and post processed result to the caller. I am unable to figure out how to do this in a composer transaction. It seems transactions are purely for data mutation and they seem to have a predefined shape of the result that is returned to the caller.
Using queries.qry will not work as there is some post processing involved.

Answer (score 0):

in a business network, you can create a Transaction you can `getAssetRegistry()` etc or run a query (eg if that's how you 'derive' what two assets to list) in your TP function . You can then process the results within a business network but TP functions don't return 'data' - you would usually use a client App to do a nodeJS `request` call on the transaction endpoint (above) via REST API or HTTPClient then process the results as you say. Eg https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/integrating/call-out - or use Node-Red https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/integrating/node-red

see also [Hyperledger composer javascript return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597701/hyperledger-composer-javascript-return-value) for info on return value from a TP function.